# How to create Time-Series Plots for three countries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am tasked with creating a function that contains 3 countries (US, Canada and China) as my inputs and then creating subplots with their COVID cases. I wanted to know how to best do this, as I was thinking of creating a dataframe with those countries and then running a for loop within to create the subplots. Please provide some tips and tricks as to how to complete this task.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df = pd.DataFrame(data=cases_raw).rename_axis("Country").reset_index()
df
df.index.tolist() #returns the list of countries 
A = cases_raw.loc['US'] 
B = cases_raw.loc['China'] 
C = cases_raw.loc['Canada'] 

#Make US,China and Canada as inputs and create sub-plots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(12,4), sharey=True)
country_groups = df.groupby("Country")
country_name = []
for (country_name, ax) in zip(country_groups.groups.keys(), axes.flatten()):
```

[image]

Comment: You should provide a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can understand how the dataset is made. As you wrote your question we don't know how `cases_raw` is made so it's difficult to tell you what's the best way to achieve what you want. For example: what should be in the x-axis of your subplot? Date-time values? If so, are date-time values in the index of the dataframe? The best thing is if you provide here a small version of your dataframe.

Comment: You messed up the end of your code with the screenshot. Not sure if this is how it was supposed to be, please check it.